# Android Error Building Signed APK: keystore.jks not found for signing config 'externalOverride'

Tags: android, android-studio, build, apk, android-signing

I get this error when I try to Build Signed APK.  I recently upgraded to API 23 but Generated APK:s successfully after that. Im confused. Asking for help and advise how to solve this problem. Here's the error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateExternalOverrideSigning'.
> Keystore file /Users/me/Desktop/final apps/keystore.jks not 
found for signing config 'externalOverride'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --  
debug option to get more log output.
```

And the log

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease
:app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:app:validateExternalOverrideSigning FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateExternalOverrideSigning'.
> Keystore file /Users/me/Desktop/final apps/keystore.jks not found for
signing config 'externalOverride'.
```

Here is my Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.waffles.vatsandbats"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
'proguard-rules.txt'     
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile files('libs/acra-4.7.0-javadoc.jar')
compile files('libs/acra-4.7.0-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/acra-4.7.0.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'


}
```

Comment: Helpful Question, Thanks!

Answer (score 182, accepted):

I found the solution. I misplaced the path to the `keystore.jks` file. 
Searched for the file on my computer used that path and everything worked great.

Comment: I got this error after moving my .jks file to another location and forgot to update in android studio x) Thanks

Answer (score 64):

File -> Invalidate Caches & Restart...

Build -> Build signed APK -> **check the path** in the dialog

[image: Check the key store path]

Answer (score 40):

Click on **choose existing** and again choose the location where your **jks** file is located.

[image]

**I hope this trick works for you**.

Comment: exactly this is the accurate solution

Comment: Easy but that's what I needed. Thank you

Comment: Thank you So much . Your answer correct and worked for me .

Comment: This is the correct answer! I face this issue when opened an cloned project!

Answer (score 15):

**TL;DR: Check the path to your `keystore.jks` file**.

In my case, here's what happened:

I moved the project folder of my entire app to another location on my PC. Much later, I wanted to generate a signed apk file. *Unknown to me, the default location of the path to my `keystore.jks` had been reset to a wrong location and I had clicked okay.* Since it could not find a keystore at the path I selected, I got that error.

The solution was to check whether the path to my `keystore.jks` file was correct.

Answer (score 13):

This is a problem that can arise from writing down a "filename" instead of a path, while generating the .jks file. Generate a new one, put it on the Desktop (or any other real path) and re-generate APK.

Comment: Android studio let you choose a folder and that was my problem... I chose the folder, not the key file... -1 for Android Studio for letting choose something is not going to work.

Answer (score 7):

open key.properties and check your path is correct. (replace from \ to /)

*example:*-

**replace from**
"storeFile=D:\Projects\Flutter\Key\key.jks"
**to**
"storeFile=D:/Projects/Flutter/Key/key.jks"

Comment: really helpful. Jazakal Allah

Answer (score 5):

File path was culprit for me
changed filepath in `app/build.gradle`

```
storeFile file('upload-keystore.jks')
```

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem, because i don't have keystore path then i see [Waffles.inc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36176437/10063282) solutions and had a new problem In my Android Studio 3.1 for mac had a windows dialog problem when trying create new **keystore path**, it's like this

[image]

if u have the same problem, don't worried about the black windows it's just typing your new keystore and then save.

Answer (score 4):

Editing the path of the keystore file solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had an existing `jks file` which I had placed on my Desktop.

In the dialog  I chose **Choose Existing** and used **Drag and Drop** to drop the `jks file` into the dialog as per this image.

[image]

The path is then automatically determined instead of having to navigated to the `jks file` location

Answer (score 2):

When I cloned the project I faced this issue then I solved this problem by following steps:
1 - Generate signed bundle/apk from topbar->Build->Generate signed Bundle->next->add file path
[image]

2. In your build.gradle(module)

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('F:\\Sofit Apps\\niam_charging_animation-wajid_notification\\niam_charging_animation-wajid_notification\\credentials\\charginganimation_ct.jks')//your jks file path here
       
    }
    release {
        storeFile file('F:\\Sofit Apps\\niam_charging_animation-wajid_notification\\niam_charging_animation-wajid_notification\\credentials\\charginganimation_ct.jks')//your jks file path here
    
    }
}
```

hope this will solve your problem, as it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For people that have tried above,try generating the key with the **-keypass** and **-storepass** options as I was only inputting one of the passwords when running it like the React Native docs have you. This caused it to error out when trying to build.

keytool -keypass PASSWORD1 -storepass PASSWORD2 -genkeypair -v -keystore release2.keystore -alias release2 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was creating a **release** build and JKS was placed in **buildTypes.gradle**

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('<Project Path>') 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux or Ubuntu you need to use the complete path.

For example

`/home/ubuntu/.android/keystorname.keystore`

In my case I was using `~` instead of `/home/user/`. Using shorthands like the below does not work

```
~/.android/keystorname.keystore
./keystorename.keystore
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your `keystore` file name does not contain any spaces e.g.

- Not like this

[image]

*** Must be like this**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have the key but it gets saved as 'Untitled' usually in your app folder after your first uploaded version.

So all you have to do is rename it (to any name) but add the extension '.jks' then generate signed bundle again and enter password

I renamed mined from 'Untitled' to 'keystore.jks' as in the image below then everything started working as usual.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it created a file without any extension (txt). I just updated extension from .txt to .jks and it started worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

just change the location of your keystore file but on the same disk.
Note : your project and keystore file should be in same disk.