# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'

Tags: android, apk, signed-apk

I am new to android and I can't generate signed apk. I can't run my project because it says first generate signed apk. I tried invalidate caches and restart. It gives me this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file C:\Users\Lenovo\.android\debug.keystore not found for signing config 'config'.
```

Comment: for that you have to first generate KeyStore.

Comment: look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173983/android-error-building-signed-apk

Comment: I already generated the  signed apk but still getting the same error 'Keystore file C:\Users\Lenovo\.android\debug.keystore not found for signing config 'config'.'

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `key.jks` in the `android/app/` folder, just change line 4 in your `key.properties` to:

```
storeFile=key.jks
```